# Нечетные числа на отрезке

Tags: python, python-3.x

> Даны два целых числа, `A` и `B`.
> Необходимо вывести все нечетные числа на отрезке от `А` до `B`.
> ***UPD:*** Использовать инструкцию `if` запрещено!
>
> *Входные данные:*
> На вход программе подаются два целых числа: `A` и `B` (`A` ≤ `B`), по одному в строке
>
> *Выходные данные:*
> Вывести через пробел все нечетные числа на заданном отрезке

Входные данные:

```
1
10
```

Выходные данные:

```
1 3 5 7 9
```

Мой код не всегда работает: например, если `A` - отрицательное и чётное.

***Код:***

```py
a = int(input())
b = int(input())

for i in range(a - (a + 1) % 2, b - b % 2, 2):
    print(i, end=' ')
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Чтобы из четного числа получить нечетное больше на единицу применим побитовое ИЛИ с единицей: `a|1`. Далее обычный цикл от а до б через 2:

```
a = int(input())
b = int(input())
for i in range(a|1, b+1, 2): # +1, чтобы попало b, если нечётное 
    print(i, end=' ')
```

Comment: Очень элегантно и быстро! :)

Comment: Выводит числа не на отрезке а на полуинтервале

Comment: На каком ещё полуинтервале? Все правильно выводит.

Comment: При входных данных -3 21 выводит от -3 до 19, а нужно до 21. Поэтому
for i in range(a|1, b + 1, 2):

Comment: Совершенно верно. Только это же не полуинтервал.

Comment: Полуинтервал... т.к включает в себя первое и не включает второе число.

Comment: Да, точно. Посмотрел определение.

Comment: `print(*range(a | 1, b + 1, 2))`.

Answer (score 0):

```
a = -11
b = 10

print(*[x for x in range(a, b) if x&1]
```

> -11, -9, -7, -5, -3, -1, 1, 3, 5, 7, 9

Comment: if нельзя использовать.

Comment: ^^^ Новое условие автор внёс правкой уже после того, как был дан ответ

Answer (score 0):

```
a = int(input())
b = int(input())

# Первое нечётное число не меньше a
a_odd = a + (not (a % 2))
# Крайнее нечётное число не больше b
b_odd = b - (not (a % 2))

result = list(str(i) for i in range(a_odd, b_odd+1, 2))

print(' '.join(result))
```

Answer (score 0):

Решение основано на том, что остаток от деления чётного числа на 2 всегда равен 0, а остаток от деления нечётного числа на 2 всегда равен 1. Решал для себя, но на радостях решил поделиться. Пользуйтесь на здоровье)

```
A = int(input())
B = int(input())
for i in range(A+abs(A%2-1),B+1,2):
  print(i,end=" ")
```

Comment: Решение основано на том, что остаток от деления чётного числа на 2 всегда равен 0, а остаток от деления нечётного числа на 2 всегда равен 1. Решал для себя, но на радостях решил поделиться. Пользуйтесь на здоровье)

Comment: внесите, пожалуйста, текст комментария в текст ответа, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

```
a = int(input())
b = int(input())

for i in range(a + (a + 1) % 2, b + b % 2, 2):
    print(i, end=' ')
```

Поправил с учетом последней цифры нечетной и первой четной

Comment: `b + b % 2` -> `b + 1`. А так решение лучше уже было.